# Need a number to the Puzzle, rhyme

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Words on the page, meant to contrive
A specific number at which to arrive,
The rhyme is the key, and it's there you must drive,
But to count for the answer, just spell the word 'LIVE'.

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer:

> Five

I went with the clue of:

> The rhyme is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the number should be...

> Thirty-Five

However...

> The poem alludes to how many words are in the paragraph. If this were true, there is one extra word in the entire poem. Thus, I cannot be certain that this answer is correct.

Comment: Also, (ROT13) gur jbeq "vg'f" vf grpuavpnyyl gjb jbeqf, anzryl "vg vf", fb gung nqqf nabgure rkgen jbeq.

Answer (score 0):

Is it-

> four, the word LIVE has IV in the middle, roman numeral for four. Also it is a four letter word.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of @Shahriar Mahmud Sajid's answer,

> if you spell out the word live, you notice that the L, I and V are all Roman numerals; the E is not. This could mean the number is LIV, or 54.